# Multiple optional parameters calling function

Tags: c#, function, optional-parameters, optional-arguments, optional-variables

Assume that i have a function like this below
It takes 3 parameters and 2 have optional values

```
private void  myfunc (int a, int b=2, int c=3)
{
  //do some stuff here related to a,b,c
}
```

now i want to call this function like below how possible ?

```
myfunc(3,,5)
```

So i want it to use default parameter b=2

But it is giving error that way.

Here the error message

```
Argument missing
```

C# 4.5

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You need to use [**named parameters**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx#sectionToggle0), like so:

```
myfunc(a, c:5);
```

Answer (score 18):

call it like this:

```
myfunc(3, c: 5)
```

You can read up on [named parameters on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx).  Named parameters can be in any order but must follow positional parameters; i.e., once you use a named parameter you cannot use a positional parameter.